# jQuery call function after load

Tags: jquery

Need to call a filter function on some options based on a radio selected [(Link here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877328/jquery-disable-select-options-based-on-radio-selected-need-support-for-all-brows), How can I call this after the page is loaded? the radio is set from a DB call and I would like to filter the options

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(my_function);
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Function code here.
});
```

Or the shorter but less readable variant:

```
$(my_function);
```

All of these will cause my_function to be called after the DOM loads.

See the [ready event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready) documentation for more details.

> Binds a function to be executed
>   whenever the DOM is ready to be
>   traversed and manipulated.

Edit:

To simulate a click, use the click() method without arguments:

```
$('#button').click();
```

From the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click):

> Triggers the click event of each
>   matched element. Causes all of the
>   functions that have been bound to that
>   click event to be executed.

To put it all together, the following code simulates a click when the document finishes loading:

```
$(function () {
  $('#button').click();
});
```

Comment: The last variant can also be used like this: $(function() { yourCodeHere(); });

Comment: Sorry one more issue. I have the function outside of the document.ready and it is called from a click (By clicking the radio button option) is there a way to just call (Simulate) the click event on the body load?

Comment: @Phill, sure, you can use $('#button').click(). I edited my answer.

Comment: @Phil - Just to be clear on what Ayman is saying, the full answer is: $(function() { $('#button').click(); });

Comment: Thanks all but I think you miss understood me. The event is happening now with the click() but I want to also have it filter the options from the ready() as well without the click() event. Please see the post link above for the code and thanks again :)

Answer (score 19):

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {

   // code here 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Crude, but does what you want, breaks the execution scope:

```
$(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
//Code to call
},1);
});
```

Comment: **Bad answer.** This is worse than crude. It may work, or it may completely fail - and worse, the success (or not) is dictated by factors completely outside the developer's control, and *very* likely beyond the user's understanding.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
  // write your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the question in your comment:

Assuming that you've previously bound your function to the click event of the radio button, add this to your `$(document).ready` function:

```
$('#[radioButtonOptionID]').click()
```

Without a parameter, that simulates the click event.

Comment: This didn't work either, any other thoughts? Could you check the code from the link above? Thanks