# jQuery simulate click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger a function when the page is loaded. [There are many ways to do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890090/jquery-call-function-after-load)
However, when I add `$('#button').click` in front of my function, then the `getType` function is not recognized. For example:

```
$('#button').click(function getType(id) {
    //...some code
});
```

> error: getType is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Just to clarify, in this case I cannot use an anonymous function. Also, it does not matter to me whether I use `$(document).ready` or `$(window).bind("load", function()`, but using these I still get the “getType is not defined” error.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery 

IMO the answer is `$("#example")[0].click();`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You either have to make your function anonymous:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    //...some code
});
```

Or pass the function itself:

```
function getType() {
    //...some code
}

$('#button').click(getType);
```

If you just want to trigger a click, call `.click()`:

```
$('#button').click();
```

Also, your `id` parameter won't be the element's `id`. It'll be the click event object. To get the element's `id`, you can refer to the clicked element using `this`:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var id = this.id;
});
```

I suggest you read a few JavaScript and jQuery tutorials (in that order).

Comment: I think the first param of `click` is an instance of `eventObject`. So, id will always be the instance, not the `id`.

Comment: @GabrielSantos: Yep, that's what I wrote at the end of my answer.

Comment: It is confusing explain at the end, when you use id from begin ;)

Comment: @GabrielSantos: Yeah, I agree. I've removed it.

Comment: Thanks all for the help, I got it!

Comment: +1 Thanks and i enthusiastic to know difference between trigger('click') and click() and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666471/jquery-advantages-differences-in-trigger-vs-click

Answer (score 6):

You are using the inline notation so, you should use an anonymous function (no name function)

your code should be:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
      // do your stuff here
    }
);
```

---

**Beside** that, as the titles says, you need to simulate a `click` event, right ? if so you better use something like:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
// somewhere when you want to simulate the click you call the trigger function
$('#button').trigger('click');
```

see [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: This answer addresses the question in the title.  The title is what made Google think this page had the answer to my question, which it did thanks to @Abu Romaissae.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#button').click(function getType(id) {
    //...some code
});
```

Should be:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
        [...] code here
    }
);
```

`function() { }` is a callback with what code have to do when I click some element.

If you have the `getType` function, you can pass it as a callback:

```
$('#button').click(getType);
```

If you want to trigger a funcion, when page load, you can do this:

```
$('#button').trigger('click');
```

Or

```
function getType() {
    [...] code here
}

getType();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.trigger( event [, extraParameters ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) on the element.

> **extraParameters**
>   Type: Array or PlainObject
>   Additional parameters to pass along to the event handler.

The added benefit is that you can pass data to the event handler, whereas if you use [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), you cannot assign data to the object.

```
$("#target").trigger('click');
```

If you're looking to use the `extraParameters`:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "custom", function( event, param1, param2 ) {
  alert( param1 + "\n" + param2 );
});
$( "#foo").trigger( "custom", [ "Custom", "Event" ] );
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.click()` method requires a callback function. So you can do something like this instead:

```
//Define your function somewhere else
function getType(id) {
    //...some code
}

$('#button').click(function() {
    getType($(this).attr('id')); //Execute it when its clicked.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the id can not be passed the way you do:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    //...some code
});
```