# jQuery filter SELECT options based on Radio PRE - selected on load

Tags: jquery

So I posted the question yesterday ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877328/jquery-disable-select-options-based-on-radio-selected-need-support-for-all-brows)) and got the answer I needed but for the life of me I can't get this to happen if the value is selected on the body load. it only works if the user clicks the radio then it filters the options.  HELP Please!!!

the Function

```
jQuery.fn.filterOn = function(radio, values) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var select = this;
        var options = [];
        $(select).find('option').each(function() {
            options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
        });
        $(select).data('options', options);
        $(radio).click(function() {
            var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
            var haystack = values[$(this).attr('id')];
            $.each(options, function(i) {
                var option = options[i];
                if($.inArray(option.value, haystack) !== -1) {
                    $(select).append(
                    $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                    );
                }
            });
        });            
    });
};
```

How to call

```
$(function() {
    $('#theOptions').filterOn('input:radio[name=abc123]', {
        'abc': ['a','b','c'],
        '123': ['1','2','3']        
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

BTW Here is a [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/anoci) of it in action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio:checked').click(); 
});
```

That'll get it done for your example.

Comment: My pleasure! It's amazing how handy the event triggers in jQuery are during a page load.