# Jquery - Filter list box based on the combobox

Tags: jquery, list, combobox, filter

I have two lists one displays cars company and  the second one displays all the cars

Here is the first comboxbox ( The first option is ALL)

```
<select id="company">
     <option selected="true" >ALL</option>
    <option>GM</option>
    <option>Honda</option>
    <option>Ford</option>
</select>
```

here is my second lisbox

```
<select id="names" multiple="multiple" size="8">
    <option>Chevy [GM]</option>
    <option>Buick [GM]</option>
    <option>Civic [Honda]</option>
    <option>Accord [Honda]</option>
    <option>Focus [Ford]</option>
</select>
```

Based on the first combox selection , I should display only that car company cars in the second list . Even the second list has the car company name in brackets .. This is fixed format . Again from the the first list if user selects "ALL" I should show all the vehicles .

Could any body give me an idea to implement this  or code snippet for this ?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Kiran

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all browsers allow you to hide the individual items in a drop-down list, so you need to keep a master list, and then repopulate based on that.

```
var names = $('#names option').clone();

$('#company').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();  
    $('#names').empty();
    names.filter(function(idx, el) {
        return val === 'ALL' || $(el).text().indexOf('[' + val + ']') >= 0;
    }).appendTo('#names');
});
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/WsHvS/

Comment: Thanks @Alnitak for this wonderful solution . I am testing this for around 12oo records and let you know the result

Comment: FWIW this could be made faster if necessary by storing the make in a separate field so that .text().indexOf() isn't called for every row each time the list is refreshed.  I've also just changed .html() to .text()

Comment: Once again thanks . Just tested with 1500 cars and every thing went well .

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, hiding of select options only works on Firefox, so for cross browser compatibility you need to use a bit more trickery (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031740/hide-select-option-in-ie-using-jquery) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery) among others).  This is what I suggest:

For HTML, have a hidden copy of your select as well as the version you currently provide:

```
<select id="company">
    <option selected="true" >ALL</option>
    <option>GM</option>
    <option>Honda</option>
    <option>Ford</option>
</select>
<br />
<div id="namesDiv">
    <select id="names" multiple="multiple" size="8">
        <option>Chevy [GM]</option>
        <option>Buick [GM]</option>
        <option>Civic [Honda]</option>
        <option>Accord [Honda]</option>
        <option>Focus [Ford]</option>
    </select>
</div>
<select id="baseNames" multiple="multiple" size="8">
    <option>Chevy [GM]</option>
    <option>Buick [GM]</option>
    <option>Civic [Honda]</option>
    <option>Accord [Honda]</option>
    <option>Focus [Ford]</option>
</select>
```

Hide `basenames` with CSS `display:none`.

Then for your jQuery, you'll be replacing `names` regularly with a cloned version of `baseNames` and filtering it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#company").change(function() {
        $("#namesDiv").empty();
        $("#baseNames").clone().appendTo("#namesDiv").attr("id", "names");
        var val = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        if(val !== "ALL") {
            $("#names option").each(function() {
                if($(this).val().indexOf(val) < 0) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You can [see this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/5WghL/1/).

Comment: why put two copies of the drop-down list in your HTML when you could trivially clone it on load [per my answer ;-) ]

Comment: @Alnitak - I'd gladly admit that your solution is more elegant.  Mine merely works.

Comment: Thanks a lot @justkt for your kind words

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Works in FF only

Try this:

```
$(function(){
 $("#company").change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#names option").hide().filter(function(){
        var regExp = new RegExp("\\[" + val + "\\]$");
        return (val == "ALL") || regExp.test($(this).text());
    }).show();
 });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Chandu/2Zppp/

Comment: AFAIK, hide is only supported on firefox for select options.

Comment: Thank a lot for your quick response, But unfortunately this works only on Firefox

Comment: @Bujji: Yep, just realized, check @justkt's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can each() on the second select's options in change() of the first select, search for substring and set the disabled attribute. (But this solution has a flaw: not every browser supports disabled attribute for option, AFAIK.)

**UPDATE**

And if you want to hide options completely, you should consider storing items from your second select in some temp storage and re-populate that select from the storage only with items that match your criteria.

**UPDATE2**

```
    var temp = new Array();

    $(document).ready(function(){

    //save in temp
    $('select#names').children().each(function(){temp.push($(this).val());});

    //change handler
    $('select#company').change(function(){
        var pref = $(this).val();
        $('select#names').children().remove();

        for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
        {

            if(pref=='ALL' || temp[i].match('.[\\[]'+pref+'[\\]]$') )
                $('select#names').append('<option>'+temp[i]+'</option>');
        }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/

This is you wanted try to do with first option using text files or alternative option is `JSON`.

Comment: the code on that website is horrendous - storing arrays within JSON as comma separated text instead of as a JSON array?!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Tested and working with IE7 and Firefox 3.6.x

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxrBf/5/)**

**HTML:** *note the `value=""` on the `ALL` option*

```
<select id="company">
    <option selected="true" value="">ALL</option>
    <option>GM</option>
    <option>Honda</option>
    <option>Ford</option>
</select>

<select id="names" multiple="multiple" size="8">
    <option>Chevy [GM]</option>
    <option>Buick [GM]</option>
    <option>Civic [Honda]</option>
    <option>Accord [Honda]</option>
    <option>Focus [Ford]</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#company').change(function() {
    var make = $(this).val();
    $('#names').contents().each(function() {
        if (this.nodeType == 8 && this.nodeValue.length > 0 && this.nodeValue.indexOf(make) != -1) {
            $(this).before('<option>' + this.nodeValue + '</option>');
            $(this).remove();
        }
        else if ($(this).val().indexOf(make) == -1 && $(this).val().length > 0) {
            $(this).replaceWith('<!--' + $(this).val() + '-->');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hide on select options is not cross-browser.

Comment: Thanks jnpcl . Yes as justkt told this won't work on IE or on Chrome

Comment: @Bujji: Working on an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to assign a classname to the options like this:

```
  <select id="names" multiple="multiple" size="8">
    <option class="gm">Chevy [GM]</option>
    <option class="gm">Buick [GM]</option>
    <option class="honda">Civic [Honda]</option>
    <option class="honda">Accord [Honda]</option>
    <option class="ford">Focus [Ford]</option>
  </select>
```

Then based on the class you can show() and hide() like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#names>option").hide();
   $("#company").change(function(){
     $("#names>option").hide();
     $("#names>." + $(this).val()).show();
     if($(this).val() == "ALL"){
          $("#names>option").show();
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: Show and hide of options isn't cross browser.

Comment: @justkt Could be replaced with addClass and removeClass in that case. Thanks

Comment: `.show()` and `.hide()` apply CSS to the elements. IE doesn't support `display` or `visibility` on `<option>` elements, so even changing it to `.addClass()` would still fail.