# Filtering HTML select elements added by a java code as the user types in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, filter

I am using JSP with HTML.

In HTML, I have a textbox and a multiple select element. I would like to filter the options in the select list as the user types in the textbox.

I found a useful JQuery code on this stackoveflow page:
[How to dynamic filter options of <select > with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447728/how-to-dynamic-filter-options-of-select-with-jquery)

Here's the code:

```
<script>
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var select = this;
        var options = [];
        $(select).find('option').each(function() {
            options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
        });
        $(select).data('options', options);

        $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
            var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
            var search = $.trim($(this).val());
            var regex = new RegExp(search,"gi");

            $.each(options, function(i) {
                var option = options[i];
                if(option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
                    $(select).append(
                        $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    });
};

</script>
```

You could use it like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('select').filterByText($('input'));
});
</script>
```

The problem is that this code only works when the options in the select element is hard coded. 
By hard coded I mean like this:

```
<option value="something">something</option>
<option value="something">something</option>
```

However, in my case, I have a list of around 6000 values that I am adding to the select list using a java code. Here's that java code:

```
<%
 ArrayList<String> allGenes= new ArrayList<String>();
   allGenes.addAll(tree.getAllGenes()); 

     %>

      <%
       for(int i=0; i<allGenes.size(); i++)
       { %>
       var gene=document.createElement('option');
       var str="<%=allGenes.get(i)%>";
       gene.text= str;
       try
        {
            document.getElementById("inputSet1").add(gene,null);
        }
         catch(ex){
                  document.getElementById("inputSet1").add(gene);                             
         }
       <%}%>
```

The JQuery code that filters the elements in the select list doesn't filter these values that i add using java code. Instead, it deletes all of them because these values are not hard coded.

Here's my textbox and my select element:

```
 <input type="text" name="text" id="text" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 55px; width: 200px; height: 22px; right: 4px">

<select  id="inputSet1" multiple="multiple" Style="position: absolute; top: 93px; left: 55px; width: 200px; height: 200px; right: 4px; overflow-y: scroll">
    <option value="1">1</option> </select>
```

Can anyone help me to make my code filters the values I add. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the quick fix is to invoke filterByText after you have populated the option list.

```
<%
 ArrayList<String> allGenes= new ArrayList<String>();
   allGenes.addAll(tree.getAllGenes()); 

 %>

  <%
   for(int i=0; i<allGenes.size(); i++)
   { %>
   var gene=document.createElement('option');
   var str="<%=allGenes.get(i)%>";
   gene.text= str;
   try
    {
        document.getElementById("inputSet1").add(gene,null);
    }
     catch(ex){
              document.getElementById("inputSet1").add(gene);                             
     }
   <%}%>  
$('inputSet1').filterByText($('input'));
```

For the long term, I suggest you look into ajax. You would probably be better off passing data (in a format such as JSON) instead of writing java code that generates javascript code.

Comment: you just made my day. Thank you!, and this smart.

Answer (score 1):

```
The JQuery code that filters the elements in the select list doesn't filter these values     that i add using java code. Instead, it deletes all of them because these values are not hard     coded.
```

I assume by "hard coded" you mean that the values are added dynamically by javascript?  I have not tested this, but if the jQuery plugin is activated before the select has been populated it might not function correctly.. Try to make sure that the select is populated before the plugin is activated

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have the desire to look into jQuery UI but it provides an autocomplete widget that does acts very similar to what you are trying to accomplish.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

In this fiddle everything working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/peFDk/

I think that the select can be not populated at time of the jQuery work.

The jQuery that you post must run in the

```
 $(document).ready()
```