# Filtering a combo box with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

My php script uses mysql results to create a dynamic combo box which then submits back to the script to process the selections. Basically the combo box options are created with this loop:

```
foreach ($attachments as $value) {echo '<option value="' . $value . '" selected>' . $value . '</option>';}
```

I'd like to filter that combo box using jquery so I tried messing around with the plugin `jquery.livefilter`. It works great if the data is encased in `<li>` tags like this:

```
<ul id="livefilter-list">
  <li><a href="#">cool</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">nice</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">interesting</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">javascript</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">css</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">html</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">script</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">international</a></li>
</ul>
```

But can I somehow use my combo box's option tag instead of the list tag? Is there another way to filter option tags with jquery?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447728/how-to-dynamic-filter-options-of-select-with-jquery

Comment: Yes it is! And thanks - I did search before posting but didn't see this. I found my answer there.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<select id='myOptions'>";
foreach ($attachments as $value) {
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
```

Not sure why you want them all to be selected