# Filter select options based on html input with Jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm having a problem with filtering HTML select options witch are based html input. For example:
If i write t-shirt in my input i want to see only T-shirts in my select options
My code looks like this...

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="inputdata" onkeyup="filter()">
    <select name="select[]" id="filtersimilar" multiple>
        <?php foreach ($all as $row) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->id_product; ?>" itemid="<?php echo $row->name; ?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

And JS / Jquery code is:

```
<script>
function filter(){
    inp = $('#inputdata').val();
    $("#filtersimilar").change(function() { 
        var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[itemid=' + inp + ']');
        $('#select2').html(options);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: please specify exactly whether your code is failing or what output you are getting

Comment: I don't get any effect... Nothing is changing when i input something

Comment: `$(this).data('options')` => I see no `data-options` attribute anywhere.

Comment: You might check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447728/how-to-dynamic-filter-options-of-select-with-jquery

Comment: If you want the filtering to happen on keyup, then remove the `$("#filtersimilar").change()` binding.  That's saying do `var options = …` when the `filtersimilar` select element changes. But what I'm understanding is that you actually want the select element to filter when the text element changes.  Also, you have `$('#select2').html(options);`, but I don't see any `select2` element in your code.

Comment: Also, the way you're trying to do it, once you've filtered your options, you can't get the full list back. If you really want to "roll your own" instead of using a filter plugin, you'll want to save the options to an object that you can reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right answer for me was this one

```
$(function() {
  var opts = $('#filtersimilar option').map(function(){
    return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
  });
$('#inputdata').keyup(function(){
  var rxp = new RegExp($('#inputdata').val(), 'i');
  var optlist = $('#filtersimilar').empty();
  opts.each(function(){
      if (rxp.test(this[1])) {
          optlist.append($('<option/>').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]));
      }
  });

});

  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked jquery.filter documentation? (http://api.jquery.com/filter/) As @Elfentech pointed out, your referring to something that does not exist (options).

I recommend you make all options invisible with "style="display:none;", and when you do the filtering give the filtered options a "display:block;". But still, your filter method looks really out of standard. Check the documentation to understand how filtering works.