# How to load partial Json data into multi select dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have used [jQuery Tokenize](https://www.zellerda.com/projects/tokenize) API to implement multi select drop down.Using java script i have customized `<option>` tag like a template.The created multi select drop down list looks like following image.My requirement is that i have a text box it act as a filter.when i type search text as **java** my drop down should only load items `language=Java`.Please let me know is it possible to do it in front end or should i populate data that matching the search text from back end.This question is not a duplicate because in my current implementation i can search items but using `<option>` val and text.but in my requirement i modify `option` into template and bind it with drop down.So i want to search text from template.if text within template whole item template should visible in drop down.

**One item in option tag**

```
 <ul>
    <li>id:1</li>
    <li>language:Java</li>
    <li>edition:second</li>
 <ul/>
```

**Sample Json**

```
{
   "book": [

      {
         "id":"01",
         "language": "Java",
         "edition": "third",
         "author": "Herbert Schildt"
      },

      {
         "id":"07",
         "language": "C++",
         "edition": "second",
         "author": "E.Balagurusamy"
      },
      {
         "id":"08",
         "language": "Java",
         "edition": "second",
         "author": "Gihan"
      }
   ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447728/how-to-dynamic-filter-options-of-select-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

`Please let me know is it possible to do it in front end`

Yes, it's possible to do with javascript. You need to loop through select options and filter them.

You can check demo from this answer [How to dynamic filter options of <select > with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447728/how-to-dynamic-filter-options-of-select-with-jquery)

http://www.lessanvaezi.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/filterByText.html

Comment: @gihan sorry i don't undertand what you meaning. you have already working code? `i can search items` what is the problem then? provide a fiddle with your code please