# jQuery selector for select option not working in ie?

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery('#by option:eq(2)').hide();
```

this is not working in ie. Here by is the id of select element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031740/hide-select-option-in-ie-using-jquery

Comment: what does the 2 here refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in IE is not with the selector but with hiding the option as unfortunately this method is not available in IE.

There are two workarounds that you may try to accommodate for the absence of this feature:

1. Use the `detach()` function within jquery and utilize and add the option back using the `append()` function.
2. Add the `disabled` attribute on the option: `disabled="disabled"`.

I have shown both here: [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U9STq/2)

Comment: This code does not works in ie. Please see the question that its not working in ie.

Comment: I could still select a disabled element in IE. In chrome although its working fine. The detach works fine in ie. How would i attach back the element?

Comment: use the append api... $("select").append(html); the html in this case should be backed up by you in  a temporary variable perhaps before detaching from the dom