# Weird behavior in "change" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 **`select`** tags, where based on the *value selected in first select I'm show/hide the option in 2nd `select` tag* which is working perfectly.  However today I noticed a weird behavior.

[image]

When I tried to **change the option in 2nd select using keyboard down arrow, it is still showing  the hidden option.**  Really confused.  Please share your thoughts.

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ueHMP/1/), where you can reproduce the above bug as I mentioned in the picture.

**JS:**

```
$('#AboveOrBelow').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() === '1') {
        $('#InitialLeakSource option[data-aob=Above]').show();
        $('#InitialLeakSource option[data-aob=Below]').hide();
    }
    else if($(this).val() === "2"){
        $('#InitialLeakSource option[data-aob=Above]').hide();
        $('#InitialLeakSource option[data-aob=Below]').show();
    }
    else {
     $('#InitialLeakSource option').show();
    }
});
```

**PS:** The above picture is not clear in 100%, please zoom for a clear vision.

Comment: Just hiding the options doesn't make them non-selectable, you have to disable them.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ueHMP/10/

Comment: @adeneo However when I change the value by "CLICK" event it is not showing.  I'm confused why this happens only when I change option via KEY DOWN event

Comment: When you open the select, the options are hidden, but when you scroll through the options with the keys, the value of the select changes, and those options are still selectable even if they are hidden, you have to disable them.

Comment: Please note that your jsFiddle does not work at all in IE9. Adding the disabled attribute will grey out the option though.

Comment: @adeneo You should add that as an answer I think.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Yes it is not workin in IE9, do you have any idea in this behavior.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for the workaround solution.  But I would like to know why it is happening? The behavior should be same for "CLICK" and "KEYPRESS" event.

Comment: Options **can not** be styled in IE, so you can't hide them either.

Comment: @user1671639 "It's IE" - This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031740/hide-select-option-in-ie-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

just add the below line at the end of you function

```
$('#InitialLeakSource').val('');
```

please check fiddle

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Please take a look at the image I have in my question.

Comment: You answer was that when you select that when you select Above, its show Above 1,Above 2 in the 2nd dropdown. And if select Above1 in 2nd Drop down, and you move back to dropdown1 and select Below, Above1 is still there?
Just check the answer in jsfiddle

Comment: Yes I know, However if you change option by pressing down key it is still showing the hidden option.  You can easily reproduce this in my fiddle

Comment: check my answer, i have given the link, it's not show the hidden options.

Comment: +1 Same as [@adeneo 's fiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066198/weird-behavior-in-change-event/19066334?noredirect=1#comment28180624_19066198) Anyway thank you.

Comment: well I am not sure why you are saying same as @adeneo's fiddle, because I have made changes in it. http://jsfiddle.net/ueHMP/12/. and it's working fine with me. just give a go.