# Internet Explorer CSS :nth-child

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, parent-child

I have problem with :nth-child in IE.
Please run this script in IE and Firefox (I make a test in IE 11 and Firefox 44.0.2.): [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/sto1c6b9/4/)

```
<div class="dropdown"> 
<select class="dropdown-select" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
 <option value="#">Wybierz swoją szkółkę</option>
 <option value="http://xxx">1</option>
 <option value="http://xxx">2</option>
 <option value="http://xxx">3</option>
 <option value="http://xxx">4</option>
 <option value="http://xxx">5</option>
 <option value="http://xxx">6</option>
 </select>
</div>
        select option:nth-child(5){
            display:none;
            color:red;
        }
```

I want to hide 5th option.

Comment: Please provide your **code**, not just a link to a third party site.

Comment: Please run this code (jsfiddle) in IE and Firefox.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031740/hide-select-option-in-ie-using-jquery have you tried hiding option in IE11 without nth child?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2324259/1860561). Seems like IE strikes again!

Comment: Ohhhh.. Is also the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Thx for help! My solution:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("divid");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```