# Why does hide <option> in <select> works in FF but not works in IE9 jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hide() is working in FF but not working in IE9

```
 $('#list_process_select option').each(function(idx){
    if($(this).val()=="GOV"){
     $(this).hide();
    }
    });
```

My code html :

```
<select id='list_process_select'>
      <option >Hola</option>
      <option value="GOV">Hello</option>
      <option>Ciao</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: what version of jQuery do you use?

Comment: Are there any errors in F12 console?

Comment: is `#list_process_selec option` a typo (missing `t`)

Comment: Seems this will not work with JQ + IE at all, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery

Comment: Thank you but my problem is not Id (#list_process_selec) because it work in FF my version Jquery1.9

Comment: The code is fine, the problem is that IE refuses to hide the option tag, no matter what style you apply to it.

Comment: You're welcome. Workaround could be to remove the option tag and add back later when needed. Or use a select replacement like select2, chosen, etc.

Comment: see this question, i think it's duplicated question: [hide-select-option-in-ie-using-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031740/hide-select-option-in-ie-using-jquery)

Comment: I have tested all this but I can not solve the problem and I do not want to replace hide() by remove(). can you explain me how to remove and add tag when I want to using show() for exmple