# Hide option from Select in IE

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a requirement that says

> **Remove an option from the dropdown and if some users already have that value, then keep showing the value in select element as default value but
> still hide that in the dropdown. (User will able to see the value as default value but in the dropdown it won't show up.)**

[image]

I have tried

```
$('#id').children('option[value="x"]').hide();
```

This solves my problem but this does not work in Internet Explorer. And if I use
`$('#id').children('option[value="x"]').remove()`
it will remove that option from DOM and the user who is already having that value will see some other value. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

would be disabled="true" an option? It would be visible but the user can't select it.

Comment: i can only see these two options: 

disable it
or
remove and add the options with js

Comment: No, requirement says we should hide it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031740/hide-select-option-in-ie-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

This will hide the option in all browsers and disables if it can't hide.

```
$('.some-list option[id=someId]').attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();
```

To show it again use:

```
$('.some-list option[id=someId]').removeAttr('disabled').show();
```