# How to disable select tag options through jQuery? Need help

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a query regarding Select tags option. plz any one solve through jQuery.
Suppose i have two select tags, in the first select tags i have options of Languages and script and in the second tag of select i have option regarding languages & scripting. The problem is that if i select languages from 1st select tag than only languages option should be visible in the second tag. Like

```
<select id="Languages">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="1">Languages</option>
    <option value="2">Scripting</option>
</select>
<select id="Scripting">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="1">C#</option>
    <option value="2">VB</option>
    <option value="3">PHP</option>
    <option value="4">jQuery</option>
    <option value="5">javascript</option>
</select>
```

Now if i select Language option the only C#, VB & PHP should be visible and all other options will be disables.

Answer (score 0):

You could do 2 approches to this.

1. Have an string in beginning of the id's on the options elements, ie:

< select id="first_select">
< option id="lang">Lang
< option id="script>Script
< /select>

< select id="second_select">
< option id="lang_1">Lang 1
< option id="script_1>Script 1
< /select>

The on the first select bind a on change event.

```
$('#first_select').change(function () {
    var type = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#second_select option').hide() // Hide all to just show the ones matching type
    $('#second_select option[id^=' + type + ']').show()
});
```

Two: Almost the same, but instead you use 1 select for each of the types in the first select element. And on change hade and show the appropriate one.

..fredrik

Comment: Showing and hiding `<option>` elements does not work in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic template that makes it relatively easy to configure:

```
var languagePairings = {
    language1: ['languageA', 'languageB'],
    language2: ['languageC', 'languageD']
};

$(function() {
    $('#select1').change(function() {
        var $select2 = $('#select2'),
            val = $(this).val(),
            availableLanguages = languagePairings[val];
        if (availableLanguages && availableLanguages.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < availableLanguages.length; i++) {
                var lang = availableLanguages[i];
                $select2.append($('<option />').attr('value', lang).text(lang));
            }
        } else {
            $select2.empty();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First check out the article on [Selected from jquery](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/).  I imagine your code will look something like this:

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
  <option class="script">Scripting</option>
  <option class="language">Languages</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
  <option class="script">javascript</option>
  <option class="language">C#</option>
  <option class="script language">jQuery</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#select1").change(function () {
    $("#select2 option").disabled = true;
    $("#select1 option:selected").each(function () {
       var classname = $("#select1").attr("class");
       $("#select2 ."+classname).disabled = false;
     });
    })
  .trigger('change');
</script>
```

That's psuedo, off-the-top-of-my-head code, you may need to revise it a little, but the general idea is that you would assign a class to the options and use those class values to control which options are available in the second table.

Edit: Looks like hide does work on options, so you might replace "disabled = [boolean]" calls above with .show() or .hide() respectively.  Also check out this earlier question:

[Hide options in a select list using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

mutex selects:

```
<select name="st[]" prev_value="">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select name="st[]" prev_value="">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<script>
$("select[name='st[]']").live('change', function()
                                        {if (this.value)
                                            {$("select[name='st[]'] option[value='"+this.value+"']:not(:selected)").remove();
                                            }
                                         if ($(this).attr('prev_value'))
                                            {var prev_option=$(this).find("option[value='"+$(this).attr('prev_value')+"']");
                                             $("select[name='st[]']").not(this).append(prev_option.clone());
                                            }
                                         $(this).attr('prev_value', this.value);
                                        }
                             );
</script>
```