# hide() not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hide() not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570377/hide-not-working-in-ie)

Hi All, 
My code works perfect in firefox and gives error in IE. any ideas?

I have a dropdown with various options, I am trying to show/hide options in another dropdown based on the selected value.

```
function selectNames() {
var Name = $("#SelectName").attr("value");
 $("."+Name).each(function() {
   $(this).hide();            
 });
}

<select >
   <option class="Name1" value="SomeName1" </option>
   <option class="Name2" value="SomeName2" </option>
</select>
<select id="SelectName" onchange="javascript:selectNames();" >
   <option value="Name1" </option>
   <option value="Name2" </option>
</select>
```

Any help is appreciated`..`