# htmlselect value hide function does not work in IE

Tags: jquery

HI Guys,

I am trying to hide  a value in my html select. Its working fine in Firefox bit not is IE.

Below the the troubling line. Please advice

```
var searchAttributeEnum =
{
                    ProductID: 1,
                    PublisherProductID: 2,
                    Artist: 3,
                    Title: 4,
                    Publisher: 5,
                    ProductType: 6
};

$(this).parents('div.cloneRow').find(".js-CellSecond option[value='" + searchOptionsEnum.StartsWith + "']").hide();
```

HTML

```
<div class="cloneRow">
<div class="col">
<uc1:Dropdown ID="searchKey" CssClasses="js-CellFirst" runat="server" />
</div>
<div class="col">
<uc1:Dropdown ID="searchType" CssClasses="js-CellSecond" runat="server" />
</div>
<div class="col">
<input type="text" value="" class="searchText js-CellThree" name="searchInput" />
<uc1:Dropdown ID="searchPublisherType" CssClasses="js-CellThreePublisher" runat="server" />
<uc1:Dropdown ID="searchProductType" CssClasses="js-CellThreeProductType" runat="server" />
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: really it is hides value of option in FireFox? or you want to hide option of select? send your html and jquery please. and question: what is a searchOptionsEnum.StartsWith? where you have defined this enum?

Comment: Don't you think it would be a good idea to show us your HTML code, too?

Comment: updated issue added HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had that problem too a while ago.
The conclusion: IE just can't  hide individual options in a select. (I think Opera too but not sure)

Possible solution: Delete the option completely but keep all the options in a hidden second select (or array) so you could re-add them later.

Answer (score 0):

Said **Mark**

[Hiding options is not cross-browser compatible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery)

Here you can find you answer

Answer (score 0):

You should re-build the *select* from scratch every time when the element list changes. It's sounds bad, but it's quite fast (even under MSIE).

(Then you have to deal with the problem: which element will be the new *selected*, when the actual one gets removed? When it appears again (and the user hasn't selected another one), how could you manage to make the re-appearing item *selected* again?)