# JQuery .hide() ListBox option issues in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery

In a perfect world (Firefox) I could just use the .toggle option and be done with it.  However, IE and Chrome aren't able to access option elements.  By using .wrap(''), I am able to successfully hide in all browsers.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#lstAvailRates option').wrap('<span>').hide();
$('#btnToggle').click(function () {
$('#lstAvailRates option').unwrap('<span>').show();
});
});
```

Ideally, I would like #btnToggle to be able to toggle show/hide.  However, I'm having issues figuring out the correct flow.

MC

Comment: I think you have to remove option elements from the <select> element and then re-add them. <option> elements aren't normal ?block? elements so your basic hide() and show() (or any animation) won't work. I'm surprised that it even worked in Firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide options in a select list using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lstAvailRates option').wrap('<span>').hide();
    $('#btnToggle').click(function() {
        //if there are option element that are direct children of the select
        if($('#lstAvailRates > option').length){
                //wrap them and hide them
                $('#lstAvailRates option').wrap('<span>').hide();
        }else{
            //otherwise unwrap them and show them
            $('#lstAvailRates option').unwrap('<span>').show();
        }
    });
});​
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/GX68J/