# jquery multiple dropdown filter menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have pictures hiding and showing based on a multiple dropdown menu selection. I am trying to have the 2 and possible more dropdown menus working together to refine a search.

If I select an item in the first dropdown, I would like to apply the second filter and so on with any additional dropdown.

I need some help with the jquery. My current problem is the 2nd filter never kicks in. It gets overwritten and resets the filter. If possible, I would like to add a 3rd filter to narrow the search even more to find exactly what I am looking for. Here is some sample code..

```
$('select').change(function(){
var current = $(this).attr('value');

if(current == 'all'){
    $('#FilterContainer').children('div.all').show();
} 

else {

    $('#FilterContainer').children('div:not(.' + current + ')').hide();
$('#FilterContainer').children('div.' + current).show();
 }

  return false;
})
```

HTML

```
  <p>Filter: </p>
        <select class="filterby">
        <option value="all"><h5>Show All</h5></option>
        <option value="1"><h5>One</h5></option>
        <option value="2"><h5>Two</h5></option>
        <option value="3"><h5>Three</h5></option>
      </select>



      <p>Location: </p>
        <select class="filterby">
        <option value="all"><h5>All Locations</h5></option>
        <option value="nj"><h5>NJ</h5></option>
        <option value="ny"><h5>NY</h5></option>
        <option value="pa"><h5>PA</h5></option>
      </select>


  <div id="FilterContainer">

  <div class="all 1 nj">Test One NJ</div>
  <div class="all 1 ny">Test One NY</div>
  <div class="all 1 pa">Test One PA</div>
  <div class="all 2 nj">Test Two NJ</div>
  <div class="all 2 ny">Test Two NY</div>
  <div class="all 2 pa">Test Two PA</div>
  <div class="all 3 nj">Test Three NJ</div>
  <div class="all 3 ny">Test Three NY</div>
  <div class="all 3 pa">Test Three PA</div>
  <div class="all 1 nj">Test One NJ</div>
  <div class="all 1 pa">Test One PA</div>
  <div class="all 1 pa">Test One PA</div>
  <div class="all 2 nj">Test Two NJ</div>
  <div class="all 2 ny">Test Two NY</div>
  <div class="all 2 ny">Test Two NY</div>
```

Comment: Please check out my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery/13477630#13477630
You would just need to extend the concept to a third selection.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is not what I am looking for. I am trying to have multiple dynamic filters that can be used in any order to refine a search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this -

```
$("select.filterby").change(function(){
    var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e){
        return $(e).val();
    }).join(".");
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div").hide();
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div." + filters).show();
});
```

with [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6PrQW/1/)

Comment: it will filter with both select, I guess this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes. Exactly what I was looking for. Testing this with a 3rd dropdown and it works. Thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome. You can chain as much select as you like  :)

Comment: @bryan151, can you share code of three dropdown filter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('select').change(function () {
  var current = this.value; // <------get the value this way.
   if (current == 'all') {
      $('#FilterContainer').find('div.all').show();
   } else {
      $('#FilterContainer').find('div').hide();
      $('#FilterContainer').find('div.all.' + current).show();
   }
   return false;
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5DpP/)

Comment: I tried the fiddle and it still only filters one thing. After the first filter, I would try to apply the second filter but it overwrites the first one. I am trying to get the 2nd drop down to narrow the results even more. This is supposed to be a dynamic filter.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work as you requested you could try the following code:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var current = this.value;
    $.each($('#FilterContainer').find('div.all').not('.hidden').not('.'+current), function(){
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
    });
    $.each($('.'+current), function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

And adding the CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

Gives you this working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Q5DpP/5/

**HOWEVER:**

I don't think this is exactly where you will want to go.  Please play with it, and you will understand.  If you change the top filter, then the bottom filter everything is okay.  But if you then change the top filter again, it will continue to hide... basically, once something is hidden it won't come back.  This then becomes a logic puzzle, and the structure of your testing needs to be modified.  It only becomes more complex as you go levels deeper.

You may wish to consider adding/removing different classes at each filter level, and then checking on only these filters.