# Filtering Inside A Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to figure out how to use a filtering js such as isotope inside of a dropdown menu.Let me explain in detail.

I would have a set of Dropdown menus that a user would click through, in the end producing a link that is specific to what they have chosen in the dropdown menus. As the user chooses options in the dropdown menus, I would like some options in the following dropdown menus to either grey out or disappear.

On another note, I would also like to be able to filter a list of links based dropdown menu choices from the user. I was wondering if this is possible?

I am trying to do this with only HTML, CSS, and jQuery. Can someone put me in the right direction?

(hopefully what I've said makes sense...)

Comment: what have you done?  I mean I see nothing too hard to do here since in many cases, a DDL just contains option tags.

Comment: I haven't done anything yet, I've just been researching and trying to find examples online.

Comment: What is at least your thought process? If you don't know where to begin think of it as if you were doing it in RL. Separate by category, but you must assign a category somehow right? And you scan over them segregating the choices.

Comment: So, first of all, it would be good if you could link to examples you have found. Failing that, it would be good to see HTML & pseudo-code to see where you're having trouble.  

Second, can you not use this question & answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430949/jquery-multiple-dropdown-filter-menu?rq=1