# Hide the selected option in select dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<select>
   <option>Jan</option>
   <option>Feb</option>
   <option>Mar</option>
</select>
```

The value which has been selected should not be appeared in the drop down. For instance, if i select "feb", Feb shouldn't appear in dropdown.

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/jucLsmjx/

Comment: you forgot to close the last option tag properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide options in a select list using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#mySelect').on("change", function(){
    $('option:selected', this).hide().siblings().show();
});
```

Additionally **if you want to trigger the *Option Hide*** right from the start, add `.trigger('change');`:

```js
$('#mySelect').on("change", function(){
    $('option:selected', this).hide().siblings().show(); 
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: beat me to it ... and works perfectly, at least as i interpret the question +1

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `option[value=' + optionval + ']')` is wrong. You are trying to select the option by its value but `value='XXX'` attribute is missing, so try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jucLsmjx/8/

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
    var optionval = $('#mySelect').val();
    $('#mySelect  option:contains("'+optionval+'")').hide().siblings().show();;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just clone it(select element) and store it inside a variable

```
var $original = $("#mySelect").clone(true); // The argument "true" copies any event handlers.
```

Then go on and remove the selected `<option>` from the `<select>`

```
$("#mySelect").change( function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("#mySelect option[value='"+val+"']").remove();
});
```

The cloning part was for the case where you needed the original DOM element, then you can always append it to the DOM.

Comment: Hiding options is **NOT** cross-browser compatible :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery#comment6196140_1271528