# jQuery HTML form processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html-select

Is there any other way to process a form when a person choose one option from one select it changes the results in other select. Otherwise Safari browser does not execute my code.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('select[name=nm_field_3]').click(function(){
        var other_options = $('select[name=nm_field_4] option[value="120cm"]');
        var selected_option = $('select[name=nm_field_3] option:selected');
        if(selected_option.text() == 'Brown')
        {
            other_options.hide();
        }

        else
        {
            other_options.show();
        }
    });

});
```

Here js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq710agd/2/

I mean this works but not all of the browsers support it. That's why I'm looking for a proper way.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: update this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/aq710agd/1/) to let us understand what you trying to do

Comment: You can't hide `options` from `select`. You can in some browsers but not in Chrome nor IE. You need to `remove()` options and then add them back if needed: see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to change event on the 'first' select,
And update the options on the 'second'.

Working example:

```
var other_select = $('select[name=nm_field_4]');
var other_options = $('select[name=nm_field_4] option[value="120cm"]');
//Listen to change event on the 'first' select
$('select[name=nm_field_3]').change(function () {
    //Getting the selected value after the change
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    //Then do your logic
    if (currentValue === "Brown") {
        other_options.detach();
    } else {
        other_select.append(other_options);
    }

});
```

Comment: You see the probem is that safari does not support .show and .hide as well as Internet Explorer. Is there any other way?