# display: none does not work inside option tag in html

Tags: html, css, html-select, display

`display: none;` does not work inside option tag in html. Why?

html

```
<select>

<option data-color="green"> Option 1 
<div style="display: none;"> hiddenText </div>
</option>
<option data-color="red"> Option 1
</option>

</select>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oobarbazanoo/76uedo40/1211/)

[image]

I am applying the `style="display: none;"` to the node with textContent being equal to `hiddenText`. So, I am expecting not to see the `hiddenText`, but I still see it. What am I missing here?

Thank you.

If we change the div inside option to span it still does not work.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to add a `div` inside an `option` tag. [MDN quote: Permitted content: Text, possibly with escaped characters (like &eacute;)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Comment: @enxaneta, thank you. Any suggestions how can I overcome this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide options in a select list using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery)

Comment: I thought I can do it with pseudo elements but it doesn't work either. Please explain why do you need to hide text inside an option. Maybe there is a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't do this.
`<option>` tag can't contain any other tags.

Try to use some libraries like [Select2](https://select2.org/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML tags are ignored inside option tag. [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-option-element)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

after rendering the view in web browser the select text not accept any div inside option tag it will assume as a text whatever you write in option tag

if you inspect you html you will see the what html part coming in view is like this 
that's  why your div property display none not working.

```
<select>
<option data-color="green"> Option 1 
 hiddenText 
</option>
<option data-color="red"> Option 1
</option>
</select>
```