# Hide the option tag where value ="2018"

Tags: jquery

I want to hide the option field "2018" from the dropdown. following is the html code:

```
<div class="form-field-select"><select name="tourtax[pa_ar]">
<option value="0">Välj år</option>
<option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option></select>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('[name=tourtax] option[value=2018]').hide();
```

This is code is not helping me to hide 2018 from the dropdown. Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide options in a select list using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it if your name attribute is not constant

```js
   $("[name^=tourtax] option[value='2020']").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-field-select">
  <select  name="tourtax[pa_ar]">
  <option value="0">Välj år</option>
  <option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
  <option value="2021">2021</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things:

1. The `name` of the select is `tourtax[pa_ar]`, not just `tourtax`. And since that includes `[]`, you need to put the value of the name in quotes.
2. Since the value of the option starts with a digit, it's best to wrap the value you're matching in quotes.
3. Not all platforms allow you to *hide* `option` elements, but you can `remove` them.

Doing all three:

```js
jQuery('[name="tourtax[pa_ar]"] option[value="2018"]').remove();
```

```html
<div class="form-field-select"><select name="tourtax[pa_ar]">
<option value="0">Välj år</option>
<option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option></select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You might be able to just hide it if you make it not selected first, but it **doesn't** work in IE11 (it works in Chrome and Firefox):

```js
jQuery('[name="tourtax[pa_ar]"] option[value="2018"]').prop("selected", false).hide();
```

```html
<div class="form-field-select"><select name="tourtax[pa_ar]">
<option value="0">Välj år</option>
<option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option></select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do,but you have to remove the selected attribute from it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[name='tourtax[pa_ar]'] option[value='2018']").hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-field-select"><select name="tourtax[pa_ar]" >
<option value="0">Välj år</option>
<option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option></select>
</div>
```