# How do I hide Dropdown list items that contains some letters, and able to display them after a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have companies in the dropdown list that are active and deleted(deleted companies will show "(deleted)"), I want to have a checkbox to show/hide the deleted ones (client side).

```
$('#drAdvisor').change(function () { //select broker to get client
    var lic_id = $(this).val();
    getClientByBroker(lic_id)

function getClientByBroker(lic_id) {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../Admin/GetClientByBroker',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "Lic_ID": lic_id }),
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    $('#drCompany').append($("<option> 
</option>").val(value.CLIENTID).html(value.CLIENTNAME));
                });
                },
            });
        } catch (e) {console.log(e); }
}
```

[image]

Comment: how are the excluded companies identified?

Comment: in database, there is an is_del column...
    
model.SelectAllClientDetails = 
    model.FilterAccountsDetails[0].Company.OrderBy(x => 
    x.CLIENTNAME).ToList();.........return Json(model.SelectAllClientDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how your default data is in your `is_del` column, but try and replace it in the condition if necessary.

```
  $.each(data, function (key, value) {
      if(key.is_del != ''){ //change here if necessary, I do not know how it is
        $('#drCompany').append($("<option></option>").val(value.CLIENTID).html(value.CLIENTNAME + ' (Deleted)'));             
      }else{
        $('#drCompany').append($("<option></option>").val(value.CLIENTID).html(value.CLIENTNAME));
      }
  });
```