# two select options - validate and hide option not needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show a set of select option base on what is selected on another select option. I have some issue to understand the logic with the js script.

Example: 
Any advice how to hide the other options which are not used

if TV show only value `device`, `tsignal`, `blackscreen`, `other`

If Radio show only the value: `device`, `rsignal`, `other`

```js
$('#new').find('option').not('[value="device"]').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Issue:</td>
        <td>
          <select required id="test" name="test">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose an option</option>
            <option value="tv">tv</option>
            <option value="radio">radio</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="50px" colspan="3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>What is the problem?</td>
        <td>
          <select id="new" name="new">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select an option</option>
            <option value="device">device is defect</option>
            <option value="rsignal">radio has no signal</option>
            <option value="tsignal">radio has no signal</option>
            <option value="blackscreen">tv blackscreen</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You forgot to state what your problem is.  What are you having trouble with?

Comment: You can't hide `<option>` in many browsers. Choices are disable/enable or remove/replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you meant to use `.change` so when `#test` dropdown changed you check what its value and based on that show / hide `option`s, right?

```js
$('#test').change(function() {
  const options = $('#new').find('option').show();
  if ($(this).val() === 'tv') {
    options.not('[value="device"]').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Issue:</td>
        <td>
          <select required id="test" name="test">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose an option</option>
            <option value="tv">tv</option>
            <option value="radio">radio</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="50px" colspan="3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>What is the problem?</td>
        <td>
          <select id="new" name="new">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select an option</option>
            <option value="device">device is defect</option>
            <option value="rsignal">radio has no signal</option>
            <option value="tsignal">radio has no signal</option>
            <option value="blackscreen">tv blackscreen</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

**Notice** Hide `option` is not [cross browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1271503/863110)

Comment: Can't hide option in some browsers...IE and Safari for example

Comment: You mean write all the logic for them.  They didn't have to make an effort at all. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: We're not here to give people code, especially if they have not made an effort.  For the most part the OP gave the markup and asked how to do something.  They did not state what issues they were having doing it themselves.  It effectively reads as a coding request.  They are less likely to learn to do it themselves, and dig for answers, if we simply give them the answer.

Comment: Thank you Mosh Freu for the logic any advice! right now only if i select tv  the device is showing what about display two option?  is not working if i add same if statement with another option.. any advice?

Comment: Do you mean, that you want to display 2 options, not just `device is defect`? If so, [this](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) will give you the answer. Let me know if it's working for you.

Comment: thx for the reply, if i choose tv i have in the other select option only `device is defect?`. If i want to add another option by choosing tv like `tv blackscreen` is not working by adding = `options.not('[value="blackscreen"]').hide();` any advice? Goal is to have 2-3 option  thank you

Comment: No, you have to concat the selector like the link I sent you. Or, even more accurate example: https://codepen.io/edhenderson/pen/suezm.