# How to add controls dynamically on asp.net page and fill it according to previously added controls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, handler

I am developing a system going to be used by RESOURCE MANAGERS of a training institute. 
Resource manager schedules batches for different skills at different centers and assign faculties to conduct particular batch.

```
 **Batches  Timings   27-Jun-11    28-Jun-11    29-Jun-11   30-Jun-11  1-Jul-11**
                         Mon         Tue         Wed         The        Fri
```

---

```
Center-1    9am to 4pm    Skill1   Skill2       Skill3     Skill4      Skill5
Batch-1                 Faculty1   Faculty3      Faculty1  Faculty1   Faculty1
```

---

```
Center-2    9am to 4pm  Skill4     Skill2        Skill1    Skill3      Skill5
Batch-2                Faculty2    Faculty2      Faculty2   Faculty2   Faculty2
```

---

```
Center-3    9am to 4pm  Skill1     Skill3        Skill2    Skill4      Skill5
Batch-3                 Faculty3   Faculty1     Faculty3   Faculty3    Faculty3
```

---

Resource manager schedules one batch for particular center for a week at once, then he comes down to schedule a next batch for other center for the same week.

At the time of scheduling the batch there would be dropdownlists for batches, centers,skills and faculties. Resource manager selects each values from dropdownlists.

Conditions to implement this page :

1. In Row : each skill dropdown should not contain skill which is scheduled in any of the previous date for the same batch.
2. In Column : each batch dropdownlist should not contain previously scheduled batches.
3. In Column : each faculty dropdown should not contain same faculty which is occupied for the same date and time.

Now I am confused about how i implement this page so that i can able to render and fill each dropdown with appropriate values. Should I use handlers to fill dropdownlist dynamically or any other jquery/javascript ideas to implement this.
I would be thankful if i will get some help to sort it out.

Thanks,
Aarti

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to fire the validations for the constraints you require upon `submit`.

Any ways or else if you have decided to make your page look dynamic, I suggest you to use `javascript/jquery`. As using handlers would make your page take more time on `rendering response` on each `select`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275383/jquery-remove-select-options-based-on-another-select-selected-need-support-for-a) is a jquery example that would help you get closer to what you need.