# using regex with jQuery to select options from a dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, regex

i need a little bit of help with some jquery thing that i'm sure is stupid but has got me stuck.  in the first dropdown is a list of products.  in the second is a list of content associated with the products.  i need to show/hide the corrent contents in the second dropdown according to what is selected in the first.

for example:  if i select "FOO" in the first list, with value 1213, i need to select values 1213-3973 and 1213-3953 from the second list.  the values in both menus are obviously dynamic, but will always have the format given, ie: the value in contentselect options will always be {product_id}-{content_id}

at first, being not super-knowledgeable about html, i had a custom attribute set in the contentselect form which i had my jquery selector grab.  however, it appears that not all browsers like custom attributes.

as it is now, i'm not exactly sure what to do.  i was told i would need some kind of regex, but i'm not sure where to start with that.

```
<script>
function selectProduct()
{
    //reset form
    $('.form_contentselect option:selected').removeAttr("selected");

    var product_selected = $('.form_productselect option:selected').val();
    $('.form_contentselect').hide();
    /////////HELP HERE PLEASE//////////
    //$('.form_contentselect option[???????????]').hide(); //HIDE irrelevant content
    //$('.form_contentselect option[???????????]').show();  //SHOW associated content
    ///////////////////////////////////
    $('.form_contentselect').show();

}
</script>

<div class="form_productselect">
    <div class="form_item"> 
        Select Product: 
        <select name="product_id" onchange=selectProduct()>
            <option value="0" selected="selected">--</option>
            <option value="1213" >FOO</option>
            <option value="1315" >BAR</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form_contentselect">
    <div class="form_item"> 
        Select Content: 
        <select name="content_id">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">--</option>
            <option value="1213-3973" >FOO - 100 points</option>
            <option value="1213-3953" >FOO - 1000 points</option>
            <option value="1315-3965" >BAR - 100 points</option>
            <option value="1315-3949" >BAR - 1000 points</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should the second element be `multiple="multiple"`?

Comment: Ahh sorry. Now I see what you want. Just to leave only those values that relate.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/, however loading content dynamically with ajax would be a better approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately hiding or disabling options in a select in not supported cross browser. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275383/jquery-remove-select-options-based-on-another-select-selected-need-support-for).

I think your best option would be something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1275475/351366) from the linked question above.

[Here is a working demo that is supported cross browser](http://jsfiddle.net/DpS9u/4/)

html:

```
<div class="form_productselect">
    <div class="form_item">
        Select Product:
        <select id="product_id" name="product_id">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">--</option>
            <option value="1213" >FOO</option>
            <option value="1315" >BAR</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form_contentselect">
    <div class="form_item">
        Select Content:
        <select id="content_id" name="content_id">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">--</option>
            <option value="1213-3973" class="opt-1213" >FOO - 100 points</option>
            <option value="1213-3953" class="opt-1213" >FOO - 1000 points</option>
            <option value="1315-3965" class="opt-1315" >BAR - 100 points</option>
            <option value="1315-3949" class="opt-1315" >BAR - 1000 points</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allOptions = $('#content_id option').clone();
    $('#product_id').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('#content_id').html(allOptions.filter('.opt-' + val));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the path you've selected is a bit error prone. Select raises some problems in IE. You cannot just show hide your options in IE. [Proof](http://jsbin.com/ecapib/edit#javascript,html). Further, doing all those complex id's is quite tricky. Finally if there are a lot of complex relationships between your inputs, at some point your code will become completely unmanageable.

I suggest you a more elegant approach via MVVM pattern. This helps to keep your code clean by separating your `data` from your `presentation`. [Here](http://jsbin.com/uxosim/edit#javascript,html) is the working example.

P.S. It uses [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com) library.