# Hiding options from select element, when selected in another select element

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple select elements on the page that contain the same options. I want to hide the selected options from thew other select elements.

this is an example of my code

```js
var $drops = $('.drop'),
  // store a set of options
  $options = $drops.eq(1).children().clone();

$drops.change(function () {
  var $other = $drops.not(this),
    otherVal = $other.val(),
    newVal = $(this).val(),
 
  opts = $options.clone().filter(function () {
    return this.value !== newVal;
  });

  $other.html($opts).val(otherVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dropdown1" class="drop">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
</select>

<select name="dropdown2" class="drop">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
</select>

<select name="dropdown3" class="drop">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
</select>

<select name="dropdown4" class="drop">
      <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
</select>
```

In this example, if I select *test1* from the first select element, it must not be shown as an option in the other select elements and when *test2* is selected from the second select element then that must hidden in the other select elements etc.

Comment: Post full code including html

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with php or mysql

Comment: Provide  code in "Code Snippet"

Comment: Improved spelling and grammar and put the code block into a snippet. This code doesn't work in the snippet but that is why the user is asking the question.

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1275452/4108884, your case is easier because you don't need switch to search for a letter equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you need, it will not allow the same option to be selected in more than one dropdown simultaneously:

```js
var $drops = $('.drop');

$drops.change(function () {
  $drops.find("option").show();
  $drops.each(function(index, el) {
    var val = $(el).val();
    if (val) {
     var $other = $drops.not(this);
     $other.find("option[value=" + $(el).val() + "]").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dropdown1" class="drop">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
</select>

<select name="dropdown2" class="drop">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
</select>

<select name="dropdown3" class="drop">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
</select>

<select name="dropdown4" class="drop">
      <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="4">Test 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: will you  please solve this problem here is link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919129/convert-group-function-result-of-mysql-into-php-array-and-pass-as-a-parameter-t