# How to remove options from select element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have n drop-downs like this:

```
<select id="select1">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
</select>
```

with identical options. All the choices should be unique, so once the option is selected in one combobox, it should be removed from others. So, if a user selects "1" in select1 there will be only options "2" and "3" in select2.

Now, [jQuery disable SELECT options based on Radio selected (Need support for all browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877328/jquery-disable-select-options-based-on-radio-selected-need-support-for-all-brows) offers a nice solution, but how can I modify this to work with selects instead of radio buttons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

This would remove everything from `#select2` that was in `#select1`:

```
$("#select2 option").each(function() {
    if($("#select1 option[value=" + this.value + "]").length)
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Here's another alternative that removes all duplicates:

```
$("select").each(function() {
  var select = $(this);  
  select.children("option").each(function() {
    $('select').not(select).children("option[value=" + this.value + "]").remove();
  });
});
```

This removes every duplicate, leaving he option only in the first `<select>` it found it in.​

Update for your comment:

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
 $("#select2 option[value=" + $(this).val()+ "]").remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I only need to remove the selected element. So, if user selects "1" in select1 there will be only options "2" and "3" in select2.

Comment: @Lapa - Added an option for that, you can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/tdKUP/

Comment: +1 Deleted my answer as yours covers it pretty well :) But I think in your alternative approach you should also use `change` instead of `each`

Comment: @Felix - I think it's a progressive drop down situation, pick 1, then pick another, etc.  I could be wrong of course, just going off Lapa's comment.  I'm a bit distracted, having fun with this question currently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566536/looking-for-a-jquery-plugin-to-resize-expand-browser-if-too-small :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if the selects have the same options in the same order.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var selectedIndex = $(this).find(':selected').index();    
    $('select').not(this).find('option:nth-child(' + selectedIndex + ')').remove();
)};
```

I think this way is faster (but less easy to read).

Comment: This doesn't work like you think :) Once you remove the first element, the order is no longer the same, and your index is off :)