# how do I disable options based on the previous selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

I have three drop-down menus for each sample shirt; product, colour and grade.  Not all products are available in all colours and/or grades.  I would like to disable the options that are not available based on the users selection.

I've tried using this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877328/jquery-disable-select-options-based-on-radio-selected-need-support-for-all-brows/878331#878331) (using a radio select). Unfortunately, I can't get it to work with an option-selected input.

This is what I'm working on - quartus.ca/select-options.html

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically clear and re-insert the OPTIONs on every change, based on your own business logic. You cannot simply disable arbitrary items in a `<SELECT>` .