# Possible to disable/make item not visable in select list?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, selectlist

Is it possible to make an item disabled/not visable in a select list? 
What I'm trying to accomplish is to, depending on a number of checkboxes, if they are selected, the fields should appear in the dropdown. However, I do have manditory fields that always should be in the dropdown and it should all be in a serten order.

Checkboxes:

```
<table class="Fields"><tr>
    <td><%=Html.CheckBox("Field1", Model.DisplayField1, new { value = "Field1" })%> Field 1</td>
    <td><%=Html.CheckBox("Field2", Model.DisplayField2, new { value = "Field2" })%> Field 2</td>
    <td><%=Html.CheckBox("Field3", Model.DisplayField3, new { value = "Field3" })%> Field 3</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><%=Html.CheckBox("Field4", Model.DisplayField4, new { value = "Field4" })%> Field 4</td>
    <td><%=Html.CheckBox("Field5", Model.DisplayField5, new { value = "Field5" })%> Field 5</td>
    <td><%=Html.CheckBox("Field6", Model.DisplayField6, new { value = "Field6" })%> Field 6</td>
</tr></table>
```

DropDown:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Sort 1</td>
        <td><%= Html.DropDownList("drpSortColumn1", (SelectList)ViewData["SortColumns"])%></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The dropdown contains all the checkboxfields + a number of extra fields, that always should be there. There fore I can dynamically remove all and add depending on if it's checked or not. 
I need to do this in the UI as well. Ideally jquery somehow. 
So what approch is good for this? Is there a disable option? what would otherwise be an option?

Thanks!

//MrW

Edit:
I tried to do this:

```
$('#drpSortColumn1 option[value=' + val + ']').hide();
```

but that doesn't seem to work out. I don't know if it simply isn't possible to hide an option, or if I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Fields input[type=checkbox]:checked').click(function() {

        $('#drpSortColumn1').children().remove();

        jQuery.each(fields, function(val, name) {
            $('#drpSortColumn1').append('<option value="' + val + '">' + name + '</option>')
        });

        $('.Fields input:checkbox:not(:checked)').each(function() {
            $('#drpSortColumn1 option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').remove();
        });
    })
});
```

So I store a Json Object with all the orginal fields in it, and at each checkbox click, I remove all items from the dropdown, and regenerate all the items. Then I remove the values from the dropdown depending on what checkboxes was not checked.

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
$('#drpSortColumn1 option[value=' + val + ']').hide();
$('#drpSortColumn1 option[value=' + val + ']').show();
```

to:

```
$('#drpSortColumn1 option[value=' + val + ']').attr('disabled','disabled');
$('#drpSortColumn1 option[value=' + val + ']').attr('disabled','');
```

or:

```
$('#drpSortColumn1 option[value=' + val + ']').attr('disabled',true);
$('#drpSortColumn1 option[value=' + val + ']').attr('disabled',false);
```

Comment: I tried the disabled one, but the problem with that is that it showing up in the list anyway. I ended up doing this basically: storing a Json object with all orginal items in it, and for each checkbox check, clear the dropdown, regenerate it, and then remove the unchecked values.

Comment: that will consume more, and if the user has selected one that on the next new select it is included, the user will loose his selected option. hop you understand, sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here, I think that's what you're looking for : [jQuery disable SELECT options based on Radio selected (Need support for all browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877328/jquery-disable-select-options-based-on-radio-selected-need-support-for-all-brows)

You can have your own order, just make the right conditions, and I think it should rule ;)

Cheers ^^

Edit : Ok, it's not really handy in your case so here are some leads :

- try to use the attribute disabled as described by CuSS below, it will be the least costy and difficult to set. But it has the major drawback that the option is not hidden, even though it's not selectable anymore. Display:none for options only works in FF from what I remember.
- If you're ready to write lot of code, you can remove and add the fields by affecting them an id to remember their order them something like

  ...
  ...
  etc...

You have to have twice the same select, one in a display:none div, the "default" select containing all the options, and that we won't manipulate.

Then if you want to hide an option, you can remove it in the first select. When you want to put it back, and create a function insert option with two parameters : one to identify the select (select1, select2, select3.... don't know how you got), and the other for the line(s) you want to insert (an array seems the best).

Then you clone the selected in the right places in the right select, and it should do the trick, at least that's the only solution I see if you don't want to recreate it all the time, and keep the right order. Tell me if this is unclear, but I hope this helps ;)

Comment: Not really, as that example seems to be working with a predefined list with what should be enabled and disabled. I can have up to 20ish optional fields, and they can all be turned on or off( + my manditory fields). That means I need to create dictionaries with every single possble solution?!

Comment: That's what I was thinking about, because anyway you have to do something like this if you want to keep the right order. And hide() indeed doesn't work with options. I'm not sure there is a "light" solution. But if somebody has a better idea, (the disabled attribute is not fully cross browser, but if you don't need IE6 support, it can do the trick, because the option won't be selectable).

Comment: Well, concidering it's in total 25 fields at the moment, and most likely more in the future, it's gonna be more or less impossble to maintain that way. I'm afraid that's not an option. Also sounds to me like this will be a very slow, checking what combination I have at the moment and then load the right values.

Comment: Check the edit on the answer, I displayed a possible solution.