# Hide / Show select options based on another selector's option in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, show-hide

There was a similar question asked with a great response here: [jQuery disable SELECT options based on Radio selected (Need support for all browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877328/jquery-disable-select-options-based-on-radio-selected-need-support-for-all-brows/878331#878331)

I would like to know how to modify the code to use a select box instead of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
the modified plugin is:

    jQuery.fn.filterOn = function(selection, values) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var select = this;
            var options = [];
            $(select).find('option').each(function() {
                options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
            });
            $(select).data('options', options);
            $(selection).change(function(){
                    $(selection + " option:selected").each(function(){
                        var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
                        var haystack = values[$(this).attr('id')];      
                        $.each(options, function(i){
                            var option = options[i];
                            if($.inArray(option.value, haystack) !== -1) {
                        $(select).append(
                        $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                        );
                    }
                        });
                    });
                });
        });
    };

        $(function() {
        $('#theOptions').filterOn('#dropDown', {
            'abc': ['a','b','c'],
            '123': ['1','2','3']        
        });
    });
```

and sample  HTML is:

```
<select id="dropDown">
    <option value="abc" id="abc" >ABC</option>
    <option value="123" id="123">123</option>
</select>

<select id="theOptions">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>

</select>
```

For completeness here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/oyaho4)

Comment: ...and a demo? I've up-voted, but it's nice to see a demonstration of something working, too =) Perhaps [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?