# Jquery function when I choose a radio button it filters values

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery disable SELECT options based on Radio selected (Need support for all browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877328/jquery-disable-select-options-based-on-radio-selected-need-support-for-all-brows)

I have two radio buttons

```
<html>
<input type="radio" class="status" name="status" checked="checked"   value="New" />New
<input type="radio" class="status" name="status"  value="Used" />Used

<select id="Insurance_type">
    <option>Home Used Insurance1</option>
    <option>Home New Insurance1</option>
 <option>Home Used Insurance2</option>
    <option>Home New Insurance2</option>

</select>
</html>
```

I need a Jquery script when I choose the New radio button, that will filter the drop down list. That I'll have only the new Insurance type.

Comment: you want to filter dropdown list or options?

Comment: I need to filter the values in the drop down list :for example if I check New I should have Home New Insurance1 and Home New Insurance 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for new button add id to this radio button-

```
<input type="radio" class="status" name="status" checked="checked" id="new"  value="New" />New    


$('#new).click(function(){   
     $('#Insurance_type option').each(function(i, option){
        if($(option).text().indexOf('new Insurance') < 0){
             $(option).remove();
        }

   })

});
```

do it for other radio buttons.
not tested, but i think this should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to do it like this:

```
$('input[name="status"]').change(function(){
    $('#Insurance_type option').show();
    $('#Insurance_type option:contains("'+$(this).val()+'")').hide();
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/mknvv/21/

<strike>*off to figure out why `.siblings().show()` doesn't work there...*</strike>

**edit**
Using `sibling();`

```
var a = '#Insurance_type option:contains("'+$(this).val()+'")';
$(a).show().siblings().not(a).hide();
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/mknvv/55/

Answer (score 0):

Try this JavaScript, replacing the id's to the ones you use on your page:

```
$("#homeUsedInsurance1").bind("focus blur click",function(){
    $("#dropDownList").html("<option value=one>option one</option><option value=two>option two</option>");
});
```

And just repeat for all the other radio buttons.

Ad@m

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.status').change(function() {
    var v = $('.status:checked').val(); // get chosen value
    $('#Insurance_type option').hide(); // first hide all
    $('#Insurance_type option:contains("' + v + '")').show(); // Show only those that contain value
    $('#Insurance_type option:visible:first').attr('selected', true); // myst select a non-hidden value!
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm4gF/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a repeated question, see the answer with function here [jQuery disable SELECT options based on Radio selected (Need support for all browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877328/jquery-disable-select-options-based-on-radio-selected-need-support-for-all-brows)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to have an extra select element:

```
<input type="radio" class="status" name="status" checked="checked"   value="New" />New
<input type="radio" class="status" name="status"  value="Used" />Used

<select id="used" style="display: none">
    <option>Home Used Insurance1</option>
    <option>Home Used Insurance2</option>
</select>

<select id="new">
    <option>Home New Insurance1</option>
    <option>Home New Insurance2</option>
</select>
```

Then you could just show/hide each one when the radio box is checked:

```
$(".status").change(function(){

    var $new = $("#new"),
        $used = $("#used");

    if( $(this).val() == "New" ){
        $new.show();
        $used.hide();
    } else {
        $new.hide();
        $used.show();        
    }

});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/BEC38/