# dropdown selection click function only works once

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to narrow down my selections of towns when the user selects a county. The following only works once:

```
$('#county > option').live("click",function(){

    var clicked_county = $(this).val();
    $('#town > option').not("."+clicked_county).hide();
});


<select name="county" id="county">
  <option>All Countys</option>
  <option>Middlesex</option>
  <option>Berkshire</option>
  <option>Bedfordshire</option>
</select>

<select name="town" id="town">
  <option>All Towns</option>
  <option class="Middlesex">Ruislip</option>
  <option class="Middlesex">Hillindon</option>
  <option class="Uxbridge">Uxbridge</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you hide the options that aren't needed but never show them again when the selection changes. So the simple solution is just to say:

```
$('#town > option').show().not("."+clicked_county).hide();
```

However, hiding options doesn't work in all browsers - for some browsers you need to actually remove them, so I'd suggest something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $town = $("#town"),
        // get a copy of all the towns
        $towns = $("#town > option").clone();

    $("#county").change(function() {
        var selCounty = $(this).val();

        // remove all, then add back in the appropriate ones
        $town.children().remove();
        if (selCounty=="All Countys")
           $town.append($towns);
        else
           $town.append($towns.filter("." + selCounty));
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VQ7CJ/

(Note: You can use the change event on the select rather than the click event on every option. Also I wouldn't use `.live()` unless the element(s) you want to attach event handlers will be created/changed dynamically after binding the handler, which I don't think is the case here, and in any case `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, so use `.on()` instead, or `.delegate()` if you're on an earlier version.)

Answer (score 2):

You are hiding the options based on selection from #county.. but you have to show them back when other option is selected..

Try

```
$('#town > option').show().not("."+clicked_county).hide();
```

Comment: @user971824 Notice that this solution shouldn't be cross-browser compatible, especially older versions of IE. See my answer for more info.

Comment: Thanks Christofer Eliasson how exactly do I convert it to be cross browser compatible?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271503/hide-options-in-a-select-list-using-jquery) using `.hide()` to hide options from a select-element isn't cross-browser compatible.

Instead I guess you have to actually `.remove()` them from the list. You could store a complete list of options in a variable in the meantime, so that you can restore the options if the user chooses another county.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877328/jquery-disable-select-options-based-on-radio-selected-need-support-for-all-brow/878331#878331) presents a small jQuery plugin to give you cross-browser support for a similar need.

Another solution would be to use the `disabled="disabled"` to disable the options you don't want. They would of course still remain in the list, but the wouldn't be selectable.

Answer (score 0):

this should work , check the javascript :

```
<select name="county" id="county">
  <option>All Countys</option>
  <option>Middlesex</option>
  <option>Berkshire</option>
  <option>Bedfordshire</option>
</select>

<select name="town" id="town">
  <option>All Towns</option>
  <option class="Middlesex">Ruislip</option>
  <option class="Middlesex">Hillindon</option>
  <option class="Bedfordshire">Uxbridge</option>
</select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#county').live("change",function(){
    $('#town > option').show();
    var clicked_county = $(this).val();
    $('#town > option').not("."+clicked_county).hide();
  });
</script>
```