# Zend framework - How to enable options in select box

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I use this piece of code to disable options of a select box in Zend Framework:

```
$this->getElement('selectbox')->setAttrib('disable', $disabled_options);
```

But I don't know how to re-enable them or clear these attributes by php code. Could you please tell me how can I achieve this goal?

Is there any method like `setAttrib('enable', $options);` ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using '**disabled**' attribute...
then to remove it use `unset($this->getElement('selectbox')->disabled);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is better to just remove unnecessary options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/878331/1333512 
[Demo](http://jsbin.com/anoci)