# disable SELECT options based on Radio selected do not work with jquery 3.4.1

Tags: jquery

I got some jQuery code from another post that was asked about 11 years ago: [jQuery disable SELECT options based on Radio selected (Need support for all browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877328/jquery-disable-select-options-based-on-radio-selected-need-support-for-all-brow)

but it only work with jquery 1.3.2

can anybody make it work with jquery 3.4.1

here is my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
A: <input type="radio" name="abc123" value="1" id="a"/>
B: <input type="radio" name="abc123" value="2" id="b"/>
C: <input type="radio" name="abc123" value="3" id="c"/>

<select id="theOptions">
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4</option>
  <option value="5">option 5</option>
  <option value="6">option 6</option>
</select>



<script>
$(function() {

$("input:radio[@name='abc123']").click(function() {
   if($(this).attr('id') == 'a') {

      
      $("#theOptions option[value='3']").attr("disabled","disabled");
      $("#theOptions option[value='4']").attr("disabled","disabled");
      $("#theOptions option[value='5']").attr("disabled","disabled");
      $("#theOptions option[value='6']").attr("disabled","disabled");
      $("#theOptions option[value='1']").attr("selected","selected");
      $("#theOptions option[value='1']").attr("disabled","");
      $("#theOptions option[value='2']").attr("disabled","");


   }


});

});

</script>
```

Comment: Why did you capitalize select?  It makes your question look like a SQL question.

Comment: Please give a look here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ (Simply remove the "@" symbol from your selectors in order to make them work again.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code working with a newer jQuery version and without the @ symbol.  I'm guessing that you will want to add code in an else statement to re-enable the select menu options when the B or C radio buttons are clicked.

```js
$(function() {    
  $("input:radio[name='abc123']").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'a') {
        $("#theOptions option[value='3']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#theOptions option[value='4']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#theOptions option[value='5']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#theOptions option[value='6']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#theOptions option[value='1']").attr("selected", "selected");
            $("#theOptions option[value='1']").attr("disabled", "");
            $("#theOptions option[value='2']").attr("disabled", "");
        }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
A: <input type="radio" name="abc123" value="1" id="a"/>
B: <input type="radio" name="abc123" value="2" id="b"/>
C: <input type="radio" name="abc123" value="3" id="c"/>

<select id="theOptions">
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4</option>
  <option value="5">option 5</option>
  <option value="6">option 6</option>
</select>
```